# linux ssh tunneling limitation per user

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

i want to limit the ssh tunneling per user I did create a user with only ssh tunneling permission ( no shell, no directory ) now I want to limit this user not be able to connect multi devices simultaneously to this tunnel ( I don't want to bind device's mac address to the user since they might change their device or firewall things ). does changing the user maxlogin on /etc/security/limits affect ssh tunneling limits?
i did use this on /etc/security/limits:
usertest          -       maxlogins       1
I still can tunnel with 2 device with same user simultaneously to the server !